# Getting more incremented output in pre increment operator in C

Tags: c

I am trying to learn pre increment operator in C. I have made a sample code and tried to understand the output:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define max(a,b) (a>b ? a:b)
int main()
{
    int I =1;
    int j=2;
    int k = 0;
    k = max(++I,++j); 
    pirntf("%d",k);
}
```

I am getting 4 as output. Shouldn't it be 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code expands to:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define max(a,b) (a>b ? a:b)
int main()
{
    int I =1;
    int j=2;
    int k = 0;
    k = (++I>++j ? ++I:++j); 
    printf("%d",k);
}
```

You can see that the value will be incremented twice.